# Want to mask some area in an image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-masking

I want to mask some area (Blue and Red) in an image, I tried different methods but I couldn't get the solution that I want.

Here's the image I am using:
[image]

Here's the result that I want:
[image]

Please explain the code because I really want to learn how it works and implement it in my own understanding.
Any helps ? Thanks

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: Do input images always come with rectangle-like blue and red regions, or did you add them manually for clarification? Also, the result seems resized (smaller) - what's the rule for resizing?

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the code you have used to get that image.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Are you trying to do object detection and segmentation? Or you already know the position and shape of the objects and just want to obtain the binary mask?

Comment: @Aulia Do you either know your input co-ordinates or features/blobs in the input image?